# HTML5: dragover(), drop(): how get current x,y coordinates?

Tags: drag-and-drop, html

How does one determine the (x,y) coordinates while dragging "dragover" and after the drop ("drop") in HTML5 DnD?

I found a webpage that describes x,y for dragover (look at e.offsetX and e.layerX to see if set for various browsers but for the life of me they ARE NOT set).

What do you use for the drop(e) function to find out WHERE in the current drop target it was actually dropped?

I'm writing an online circuit design app and my drop target is large.

Do I need to drop down to mouse-level to find out x,y or does HTML5 provided a higher level abstraction?

Answer (score 30):

The properties `clientX` and `clientY` should be set (in modern browsers):

```js
function drag_over(event) {
        console.log(event.clientX);
        console.log(event.clientY);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    function drop(event) {
        console.log(event.clientX);
        console.log(event.clientY);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

[Here's a (somewhat) practical example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/kKuqH/30/) that works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Do you know why on Safari and Chrome when the text is drop, it does not stay exactly at the same position? The dragged element is shifted a few pixel.

Comment: @Charles I tried it in Chrome (on Windows) and I'm not seeing it, if you figure out what it is please let me know

Comment: Nice idea, however the clientX and clientY are going to be inaccurate proportional to the distance of the cursor from the upper left corner of the element which was dropped.

Comment: @robertc what about if I want to associate dragged items to other items on the page? Like other boxes or words and produce an error for incorrect associations?

Answer (score 4):

To build on top of robertc's answer and work around the issue:

> The clientX and clientY are going to be inaccurate proportional to the distance of the cursor from the upper left corner of the element which was dropped.

You may simply calculate the delta distance by subtracting the client coords recorded at `dragStart` from the client coords recorded at `dragEnd`. Bear in mind the the element which was dropped still has the exact same position at `dragEnd` which you may update by the delta distance to get the new left and top positional coordinates.

Here's an [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-html-drag-and-drop?file=index.tsx) in react, although the same can be accomplished in plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of the event object which return the coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to the top-left corner of the document:

```js
/* events fired on the draggable target */
const source = document.getElementById("draggable");
source.addEventListener("drag", (event) => {
    const [x, y] = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
    console.log(`The element is being dragged at (${x}, ${y})`);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(1, 1, 25);
    /* Prevent the user selecting text in the example */
    user-select: none;
}

#draggable {
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}

.dropzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blueviolet;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true">This div is draggable</div>
</div>
```