# HTML5 drag and drop to move a div anywhere on the screen?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

The title is pretty self explanatory.

All the demos I've found consist in dropping a div to a certain location. E.G a trashcan. I need to make a draggable div that can be dropped anywhere on the screen.

Is it possible to do this with HTML5? if not how should I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Drag and Drop anywhere on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230834/html5-drag-and-drop-anywhere-on-the-screen)

Comment: If you want to do it the Jquery way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47521404/6901876) is the best solution, and far easier than the pure Javascript solution.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's quite straightforward really:

1. In the `dragstart` event calculate the offset between where the user clicked on the draggable element and the top left corner
2. Make sure the `dragover` event is applied to the entire document so the element can be dropped anywhere
3. In the `drop` event, use the offset you calculated with the `clientX` and `clientY` of the drop to work out where to position the element

[Here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/kKuqH/) I [prepared earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230834/html5-drag-and-drop-anywhere-on-the-screen).  For bonus points you can update the top and left position of the element in the [dragover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438320/html5-dragover-drop-how-get-current-x-y-coordinates), this is useful if the bit you're allowing to be dragged isn't the whole element that needs to be moved.

Comment: @Luis, while dragging the element you can set `iframe { pointer-events: none; }` and you can drag element over the iframe

Answer (score 0):

To add to 2nd point in @robertc's answer, to make an element droppable anywhere in the entire document, the `drop` event can be listened to `document.documentElement` instead of `body`.

In some cases, `body` may not have the exact dimensions of the page and therefore, the element cannot be dragged outside the boundary of `body`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76814273/2919438) is the solution I proposed.