# Javascript framework for draggable objects on web browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, draggable

What would be the best Javascript framework to implement objects that can be dragged around the window and hovered over to make other objects appear?

I was thinking about AngularJS but is that the best choice? jQuery doesn't seem to be versatile enough.

Also, which one is the most cross-browser compatible?

Thanks

**Edit: jQuery UI could be an option but it seems that what I am trying to do would be animation-heavy and a framework using hardware acceleration would be more suitable than one using browser acceleration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only going to get native acceleration using HTML5 in combination with CSS3. To that end, [there are means](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/create-drag-and-drop-features-html5-4112945) of implementing something similar to dragability, which, [in combination with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278409/html5-drag-and-drop-to-move-a-div-anywhere-on-the-screen), may achieve what you need via the events. JS still required, but much, much less.

The downside is that you lose browser compatibility. To remedy this, check out [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). You can add in jQuery UI if a legacy browser accesses your site, but otherwise stick with HTML5. As you can guess, doing animations without Flash and with native acceleration AND browser compatibility can get hairy quickly.