# How can i get the drop point indormation? [drag and drop]

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

now im trying to implement drag and drop on html5.
I'd like to know how I can catch the information where I drop content.
for example...

`<div id="droppoint"></div><ul>
    <li draggable="true">1</li>
    <li draggable="true">2</li>
    <li draggable="true">3</li>
    <li draggable="true">4</li>
    <li draggable="true">5</li>
    </ul>`

When I drag this li element to droppoint and drop this, I want to catch this id attribute(droppoint).

```
erea.addEventListener("drop", function(evt) {

  var droptext = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  console.log('============================');
  console.log(droptext);
  console.log('============================');

  evt.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function drag_over(event) {
    console.log(event.clientX);
    console.log(event.clientY);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
function drop(event) {
    console.log(event.clientX);
    console.log(event.clientY);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/kKuqH/30/

clientX and clientY are current client's coordinates (his pointer), so if you get client's coordinates while he drops, you know where he dropped the item.

Found it here: [HTML5: dragover(), drop(): how get current x,y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438320/html5-dragover-drop-how-get-current-x-y-coordinates)

Have a good day =)

Comment: sorry I should have written more clearly...
I don't want to know the coordinates where I dropped.
I want to know the id name or class name where I drop.

On my code, I want to catch "droppoint" strings...

but thank you for your immediate response. :)

Comment: In this example,I want to receive "content".
Not "dragme"...

hard to explain it ...

Comment: You want innerHTML of the dragme? then just get the .innerHTML of the item dropped and add it to the target =)