# How to get position(x y coordinates) of moving objects in React Beautiful DND?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using React Beautiful DND and i would like to get position(X Y) of objects that i drag on screen. Anyone knows how to get that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5: dragover(), drop(): how get current x,y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438320/html5-dragover-drop-how-get-current-x-y-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

I used the `mousemove` event listener in `useEffect` to get the current mouse position and saved it in a `ref` variable.

Then, inside the `onDragEnd` method I got the current location from the ref variable. You can also use `onDragStart` based on your requirement. Here's my example-

```js
const mouseLocation = useRef({x:0,y:0});

const logMousePosition = e => {
  // these are the cordinates of your current pointer position
  mouseLocationRef.current.x=e.clientX;
  mouseLocationRef.current.y=e.clientY;
}
useEffect(()=>{
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", logMousePosition);
},[])

const onDragEnd = () => {
  const {x,y} = mouseLocationRef.current;
}

return (
  <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
    .
    . // Your render code here
    .
  </DragDropContext>
);
```